# Is there a name for verbs that describe regular activities?

Tags: verbs

Basically I mean, for activities one consistently performs, is there a special name or category for those verbs?

Examples:
He **runs**
I **play** table tennis 
She **surfs**
They **study** linguistics

See how each of these words describe something one often does, but not necessary what they're currently doing.

Comment: In English, the simple present form ("He runs.") is 'habitual'.

Comment: They are called action or active verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a property of the verb, in the sense "verb root", it's a property of the form ("tense"). You can construct huge numbers of parallel forms "I verb X" / "I am verbing X" with this same property -- insert sing, eat, carry, hammer, etc. Aiming for terminology that is consistent across languages, "I eat/sell/make cheese" exemplifies the habitual, and "I am eating/selling/making cheese" exemplifies the present progressive".